# Textures unbinding when text isn't drawn (LWJGL/Slick-util)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've been working on a game with LWJGL and came to a weird problem. Every time I decide to hide the text my textures seem to unbind. Here's all the code that is invlolved

Below is the code inside my Text class.

```
public void draw() {
        for (TextData textData : textList) {
            drawString(textData.getX(), textData.getY(), textData.getText());
        }
    }

void drawString(int x, int y, String text) {
        for (String line : text.split("\n"))
            ttf.drawString( x, y += ttf.getHeight(), line);
    }
```

Now the code in the main class

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_H)) {
                hideText = !hideText;
        }

if (!hideText) {
            text.draw();
        }
```

This is the result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y9fk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUoOf.png

Comment: Are you sure it unbinds the texture? I suspect that this is probably done using the fixed-function pipeline and the implementation of `drawString (...)` has a side-effect of enabling (and leaving enabled) `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, which is being disabled elsewhere in your code. Without the call to `drawString (...)` `GL_TEXTURE_2D` may never be re-enabled. This is all intuition / speculation since I have no idea how **ANY** of this code is actually related to the underlying OpenGL API calls. It almost certainly has nothing to do with the bound texture, but some other texture-related state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful consideration of my code I found out my Entity class was calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` while it was being drawn and drawing the text was enabling it again. Adding `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);` at the end of my Entity drawing code fixed the problem. Thanks to the comments for helping me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When text is drawn an image is bound to draw the text, i'm guessing that usually lwjgl/slick saves the current texture when drawing text and then rebinds it after.  I would guess that it might be a bug where when hidden it doesn't rebind the texture but still binds another texture?